# How to define an array of Strings in spring's xml configuration to satisfy Intellij Idea?

Tags: spring, intellij-idea

I use the following xml-configuration:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.BeanNameAutoProxyCreator">
    <property name="beanNames">
        <array value-type="java.lang.String">
            <value>someService</value>
        </array>
    </property>
    <property name="interceptorNames">
        <array value-type="java.lang.String">
            <value>managerSecurity</value>
            <value>teamSecurity</value>
        </array>
    </property>
</bean>
```

And it works. But Intellij Idea gives me an error:  **expected, got 'stringValue'**
I wonder what is the proper way to define an Arrays of string-values in Spring configuration to satisfy Intellij idea validation? 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you might have configured some language injection for the  tag body. To verify, please press Alt+Enter while cursor is positioned inside, if you get intention to "Edit ... Fragment" then this is the case. Please check manual Language Injection settings in *File | Settings | Editor | Language Injections* and/or try disabling 3rd party plugins which might be causing this.